# Moving this question from another Stack Exchange site or ask a duplicate on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, migration

I have posted the question linked (https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/163068/location-and-filenames-of-wireless-drivers-on-android-5-02-kernel-3-10-49) on Android SE.

I believe Stack Overflow may be a better place for it due to feedback, lack of responses on Android SE, and topics Android SE state they cover.

I am also considering other Stack Exchange sites such as Unix & Linux SE.

Would it be better for the original question to be moved, or another to ask the question here and create a duplicate on two different sites across Stack Exchange?

I did search Stack Overflow for this type of question, however the results weren't relevant, hence asking here.

I wasn't sure what tags to use that were relevant, hence ones currently chosen.

Comment: Did you not find this in your research: http://blog.linuxconsulting.ro/2010/04/porting-wifi-drivers-to-android.html

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't fit here.  You're looking to fuzz wireless drivers, which is a thing that depends on the hardware (phone) you're running and whatever tools you have at your disposal.

The problem with this is that there isn't really anything that Stack Overflow would be suited to answer here.  If you know the make and model of your phone, you can likely find the drivers online.  You also may run afoul of some EULAs since those drivers are proprietary and reverse-engineering is expressly forbidden (although we're not the police and won't likely contest a question on that ground alone).

I may be wrong since I don't frequent the Android tag, but I don't see it necessarily being on topic here.

Comment: Would fuzzing open source android code be allowed?